# dynamic binding using @Query spring data mongorepository

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, mongorepository

From the below json I want to retrieve the data for Country,categories etc based on user request parameter.How can I do that?
below code snippet I am using for mongo repository

```
@Query(value = "{ 'offeringInfo.offeringId' : ?0}", fields = "{'fields':1}")
Offering findOfferingByFields(String offeringId, String fields);

{ 
  "_id" : "PMRS774616-PICSD215", 
  "offeringInfo" : { 
    "service" : "HBOGO", 
    "mindOfferingId" : "PMRS774616", 
    "offeringType" : "FEATURE", 
    "offeringId" : "PMRS774616-PICSD215" 
  }, 
  "categories" : [ "Late Night Movies" ], 
  "country" : { 
    "name" : "US", 
    "isoCode" : "840", 
    "startDate" : "2015-09-09T06:00:00.000-04:00", 
    "endDate" : "2016-12-31T00:00:00.000-05:00" 
  }, 
  "photos" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: User request parameters:
--------
"api/v1/abc/12345?fields=categories"
----------
Possible inputs:
----------
fields= Categories,country
fields= Categories
fields= country

Comment: You cannot dynamically change the query structure of a `@Query` annotation based on user input.  You have to either define multiple queries for each potential parameter combination, or implement a method that will dynamically build the query.  The latter can be done with Spring Data MongoDB's `MongoTemplate` and `Criteria` API.